# Angular 17 router.navigate is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular17

I have an angular application with two pages: The first one with a form and the second one with other data. I have a button and in onclick event i navigate to results page. Sometimes, the router.navigate does not work at the first time. I need to press the button two times to get the navigation. This is the function (the timeout is because i was testing if with that works, but the ideal version is without using it, but still not working some times on the first time). router is Router from Angular:

```
public goToResults() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      setTimeout(() =>
        this.router.navigate(["resultados/es"]) 
      , 500);
    }
    else {
      this.showErrors = true;
    }
  }
```

This the app.routes file:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'datos/:lang', component: UserDataComponent },
    { path: 'resultados/:lang', component: ResultsComponent, canActivate: [ReloadGuardService] },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/datos/es', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

I debugged the code and it enters in the timeout and executes the navigate line, but sometimes works and sometimes not, it is random. There is no error in the console also.

Do you know what is wrong or what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u add code in this stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how you use the navigate function which accept an array, try to do this:

```
this.router.navigate(["resultados", "es"]);
```

I hope this helps you, regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried before but the same behavior happens. Both syntax are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, I had to import the provideHttpClient() module in app.config.ts and then it worked fine for me.  I'm not sure if this works for 100% of cases, the page I was routing to had an service I was using which wasn't working because of the lack of the provideHttpClient().  This is a potential solution:

app.config.ts

```
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

providers: [provideHttpClient()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my project:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router) {}
    
onAuth() {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('profile')
  });
}
```